# get grandson text using xml document in c#

Tags: c#, xmldocument

I'm using XmlDocument in C# and I would like to know how to get grandson data of the root?

```
<tRoot>
   <One>
   <a>15</a>
   <b>11</b>
   <c>1</c>
   <d>11.35</d>
   <e>0</e>
   <f>289</f>
 </One>
 <Two>
   <a>0</a>
   <b>11</b>
   <c>1</c>
   <d>0.28</d>
   <e>0</e>
   <f>464</f>
</Two>
</tRoot>
```

and I want the ability to get a of One and also a of Two

I tried:

```
var doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(Consts.FileConst);
var docXml = doc["One"];
if (docXml != null)
{
   float valFromXml = float.Parse(docXml["a"].InnerText);
}
```

The issue is that docXml is null

Any assitance?

Comment: What have you tried and where are you stuck?  Please include your code.  Is there any reason you're using the old `XmlDocument` API rather than the much nicer `XDocument`?

Comment: @CharlesMager I edited my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested above, XDocument would be a better alternative. If, however, you still want to use XmlDocument, you can iterate through the children using

```
var doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(Consts.FileConst);
foreach(XmlNode xmlNode in doc.DocumentElement.ChildNodes) {
  //access a/b/c/d/e using:          
  xmlNode.ChildNodes[0].InnerText; //for a
  xmlNode.ChildNodes[1].InnerText; //for b
}
```

Comment: I want also data of "a" children of "One" node. See my edited question.

Comment: @Programmer, Can you give me a sample output for the xml file you have provided.

Comment: Your post says "I want the ability to get a of One and also a of Two". My solution will give you a (and potentially b/c/d/e) of One and Two (and potentially Three/Four/Five.....)

Comment: The` foreach` will go through One, Two etc., and `xmlNode.ChildNodes[0].InnerText;` will give the first (zeroth) value which looks like it's always a.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
XmlDocument d = new XmlDocument();
d.LoadXml("<tRoot><One><a>15</a><b>11</b><c>1</c><d>11.35</d><e>0</e><f>289</f></One><Two><a>0</a><b>11</b><c>1</c><d>0.28</d><e>0</e><f>464</f></Two></tRoot>");
XmlNodeList itemNodes = d.SelectNodes("//*/a");
```

Comment: Run the code I provided and break your debugger once the itemsNodes collection is set. It will contain the two 'a' elements you need. Their value is in the InnerText property of each.